# How can I create an ol with a li element so that if I create a text node, it can be adding with ordered numbers on the same line in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, json

How can I make this code work well with the list printing the result on the same line.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<input id="toDo" type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" required>
<button onclick="submitText()">Submit</button>
</div>

<div><ol align="center" id="probody"></ol></div>
<script>
const mainBody = document.querySelector('#probody');

function submitText() {
        mainBody.innerHTML = '<li></li>'
        const text = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
        const myText = document.createTextNode(text);
        mainBody.appendChild(myText);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

- You overwrite the contents of the previous list when you do `mainBody.innerHTML = '<li></li>'`.
- It is not semantically correct to add a text node to an ordered list. Instead, create a `li` element and append the text node to the `li`.

Try this instead:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<input id="toDo" type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" required>
<button onclick="submitText()">Submit</button>
</div>

<div><ol align="center" id="probody"></ol></div>
<script>
const mainBody = document.querySelector('#probody');

function submitText() {
        const text = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
        const myText = document.createElement("li");
        myText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        mainBody.appendChild(myText);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added few things:

- remove the value of input when button is clicked
- check if length of input is greeter then 1
- event listener when enter key is pressed

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<input id="toDo" type="text" placeholder="Add an item!" required>
<button id="btn">Submit</button> 
</div>

<div><ol align="center" id="probody"></ol></div>
<script>
const mainBody = document.querySelector('#probody');

function submitText() {
        var input = document.getElementById("toDo")
        if(input.value.length < 1 || input.value.replaceAll(" ", "") < 1) return; // check if the input value length is greeter then 1 character
        const myText = document.createElement("li");
        myText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        mainBody.appendChild(myText);
        input.value = ''; // clear the value input
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", submitText); // save the input value when button is clicked

document.getElementById("toDo").addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') submitText();
}); // save the input value when enter key is pressed

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mainBody.innerHTML = '<li></li>'
```

to

```
mainBody.innerHTML += '<li></li>'
```